# Telerik Kendo UI for MVC- Upload widget not selecting multiple files on the server

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-ui

I installed the trial version of the `Telerik Kendo UI Suite` for my `MVC Web application`.  Locally on my machine, I am able to select multiple files and upload them synchronously. Everything works as expected on my local machine/environment. When I upload it to the `Test Environment Web Server` on the intranet, When I click the select button, it does open the dialog box but it not allowing me to the select multiple files.  Only single files.  My license will be arriving soon and I will be installing full version, but I am curious that due to the trial version, would it prohibit me to select multiple files at once on the server?

```
<div class="bodyContent">
        <span class="leftContent">Load/Result/Log Files: </span><span class="rightContent">
            <input name="file" id="file" type="file" />
        </span>
    </div>


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#file").kendoUpload(

            );
            $("#file").closest(".k-upload").find("span").text("Select");
            $("#file").parent().css({ width: 100 });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to browser limitations. Not all browsers allow you to select multiple files (especially the old ones). For example multiple file selection is supported in Internet Explorer since version 10.

I suspect you have used a different browser on your server than on your machine hence the different behavior.

More info about the browser support of Kendo UI Upload can be found here: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/upload/supported-browsers

Comment: well i have IE 10 on my machine. Locally I can select multiple files with no problem. Even their demo page for kendo upload works fine. My intranet application is on the server but I am still accessing it via my browser on the machine. I am not actually browsing the application on the server machine itself.